# visual studio 2017 can't load MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio

My visual studio 2017 can't load MySQL database.

[Already installed MySQL for VS and connector/NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm2sh.png) and
[already installed VS for database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drv95.png)

But if I pressed finish these happened:
[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXedt.png),
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUKRu.png)
and
[error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIkvt.png)

But if I use Microsoft SQL, Visual Studio can load the DB.
How to fix this? I already tried to install the developer version of MySQL but it didn't work.

Comment: I would try reinstalling the mysql for vs.  I would also recommend you verify the connection strings is correct and that the user in the connection string has permission to read the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install MySQL Connector/Net version 6.9.8 and see if that works (worked for me, had same issue with 6.9.9 and 6.10).
You can download archive versions here: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/